# Transpose multiple columns WRT to a row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, transpose

Ive searched for transpose and pivots but can't find anything like this.
Input table:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| TID |  TP1  |  TP2  |  TP3  |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| A   | link1 | link1 | link3 |
| B   | link3 |       |       |
| C   | link2 |       |       |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Required output table:

```
+-----+--------+-------+
| TID | TP Num |  REF  |
+-----+--------+-------+
| A   |      1 | link1 |
| A   |      2 | link1 |
| A   |      3 | link3 |
| B   |      1 | link3 |
| C   |      1 | link2 |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit complicated and you will need to use union all to have the vertical representation and then using user defined variables get the nums something as

```
select TID,`TP Num`,REF from (
  select TID,REF,@rn:= if (@prev_tid = TID,@rn+1,1) as `TP Num`,@prev_tid:=TID  from
  (
    select
    TID,REF from
    (
        select TID , TP1 as REF from mytable where TP1 is not null and TP1 <> ''
        union all 
        select TID , TP2 as REF from mytable where TP2 is not null and TP2 <> ''
        union all
        select TID , TP3 as REF from mytable where TP3 is not null and TP3 <> ''
    )x
  )y,(select @rn:=0,@prev_tid:=null)z
  order by TID,REF 
)x;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d15c/14

Comment: Can you  please explain what is @rn:=

Comment: @rn is a user defined variable and works for the current session of the query. So I have initialize it to 0 as  `select @rn:=0`. Now in the query I calculated the `TP Num` and checked if the previous TID is same as current one then increment `@rn` by 1 else set it to 1.

Comment: Ah,okay. I need to implement it in postgres, any idea how I translate that?

Comment: ouch i thought its mysql.. i dont know how to do it on postgres